# How to make a button to jump into specified table row

Tags: php, html, sql

I have code that generate a table from my database. The code is

```
<body>
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header text-center">ORDER</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="purchase.php">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Note</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    $sql="select * from product left join category on category.categoryid=product.categoryid order by product.categoryid asc, productname asc";
                    $query=$conn->query($sql);
                    $iterate=0;
                    while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['productid']; ?>||<?php echo $iterate; ?>" name="productid[]" style=""></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['catname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['productname']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right">&#x20A8; <?php echo number_format($row['price'], 2); ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity_<?php echo $iterate; ?>"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="note_<?php echo $iterate; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $iterate++;
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" name="customer" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-left:-20px;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkAll").click(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that code will give me a big table. Is there any way to make some link or button to make me jump onto a specific row in a table ? Because scrolling through the big table really not efficient

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i found a simple solution :
I just use `<a href="#catname">catname</a>` to simply jump into the category I needed on the table

Answer (score 0):

With what criteria do you want to jump to a specific row, is it depending on the data in the row? or the row number? ... If it is the `td` row number, add classes to the `td` element , for example: `<td class="catname"><?php echo $row['catname']; ?></td>` and create a javascript function where you can input a row number and it returns the value as so:

```
function finder(n){
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < $('td.catname').length; i++){
        return $('td.catname').eq(n).text();
    }
}
```

such that you can call the function `finder()` and it will return the value contained in the row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_button').click(function(){
        $('#my_output').text(finder($('#my_input').val()));
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry i don't really familiar with javascript. But ```<td class="catname"><?php echo $row['catname']; ?></td>``` is what i want. Now can you give me an example of using those function ? example one of the catname are burger, rice, and beverage. How do I apply those function into my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to a specific row using jQuery `.scrollTop()` method which is used to get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

Look at the below example which i have prepared to scroll in a large table:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    //here 'trHeight' is calculated based on max height of scroll container
    //formula to calculate is : max-vertical-scroll-position / no of table rows
    //you can get scroll bar position using $('selector').scrollTop()

    var trHeight = 21.824;
    $(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        $('#mytable').append('<tr class=' + i + '><td>Row ' + i + ' </td></tr>');
      }
    });

    function navigate() {
      $("." + $("#rowno").val()).addClass("highlight");
      var scroll = parseInt($("#rowno").val()) * trHeight;
      $('#container').scrollTop(scroll);
      alert("Current scroll bar position is " + $('#container').scrollTop());
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .highlight {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #container {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 400px;
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Enter row no to jump : <input type="text" id="rowno" />
  <button onclick="navigate();">Go</button>
  <br/><br/>

  <div id="container">
    <table id="mytable">
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can edit this code according to your need. read the full article about `.scrollTop` on [jQuery official site](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/).